# difference between boysurface and tetrahemihexahedron

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

Our professor wants us to use the knowledge of the $\mathbb{RP^2}$ model in three dimensions containing self-intersection and/or singularities and real projective planes.

---

After Google (of course I can see they have different shape)

Only thing I can notice is Boy's surface, no matter which angle I look at it, it still in the same shape but not for tetra-hemi-hexahedron.

and one is an immersion and the other is not.

Our goal is to use more words less formula. Which is hard.

Comment: Our goal is to help those who help themselves. Which is harsh, but fair. http://mathoverflow.net/faq http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask

Comment: yess i tried seeing one has an immersion but was wondering are there any more?

Comment: The answer of Jim Conant from math.stackexchange:

The fact that one is an immersion and the other is not already indicates they are different. Indeed, the singular locus for Boy's surface has a triple point plus a 1-manifold double point locus. For the tetra-hemi-hexahderon, there is a triple point, but the singular locus also has univalent vertices (this is where it fails to be an immersion), so the two maps of a projective plane into $R^3$ are not equivalent.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of a question on math.SE, that has an accepted answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/313346/264 Therefore, I'd recommend closing the question (unless anyone has something to add). Presumably it was posted here by the same person going under the name "MathGeek" after their question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/314115/264 was closed.

Comment: I'm heartbroken that my math.stackexchange answer was not sufficient. ;)